# MPMoviePlayerViewController orientation different to devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I have created a vimeo player by doing this in the pageView.m :

```
@interface pageView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController;
@end
```

and this:

```
[YTVimeoExtractor fetchVideoURLFromURL:vimeos
                                   quality:YTVimeoVideoQualityHigh
                         completionHandler:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error, YTVimeoVideoQuality quality) {
                             if (error) {
                                 // handle error
                                 NSLog(@"Video URL: %@", [videoURL absoluteString]);
                             } else {
                                 // run player
                                 self.playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
                                 [self.playerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
                                 [self presentViewController:self.playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }
                         }];
```

It is all working perfectly fine. Apart from the fact that the orientation is only vertical. I have set my device orientation as Portrait, as I definately don't want to change it. But I would like to be able to have the `playerViewController` as horizontal only. Is this possible?

---

I have tried this

```
[[self.playerViewController view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
```

But is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it to portrait, you can override `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` to allow landscape just for `playerViewController` :

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[playerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

That code goes in `appdelegate`.

Comment: but playerViewController is not a class?